# Is there an adapter that allows me to use a cellular phone telephoto lens (M17xP0.75) on a M37 video camera?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, adapter

I have a digital video camcorder that uses a 37mm thread mount for lenses.

I would like to try to use a telephoto lens made for a cellular phone on the camcorders 37mm threaded lens mount.

Is there an adapter solution?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the telephoto lens you're trying to mount?

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32917091175.html

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33030693932.html